# Input from keyboard in Tcl

Tags: tcl

How do I give input to a Tcl script through the keyboard? Is there any thing like `scanf()` in C?

Comment: I didn't see the (only) answer chosen as the correct one, so I thought I'd check back in... Was your question answered, did you need more information, or did I just misinterpret what you were asking?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/gets.htm) command is probably what you want.

```
set data [gets stdin]
# or
set numchars [gets stdin data]
```

The [scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm) command can be used to parse the input similar to how scanf does with C. It uses the format:
    scan string format ?varName varName ...?

Thus, to parse an input like "5 cats" to individual variables:

```
set data [gets stdin]
scan $data "%d %s" myint mystring
```

Edit: Added more information from Colin's comment.

Comment: But if you want to break the input line that gets gives you into multiple values the way scanf() does, you might want to apply the scan command (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm) to its result, eg.   scan [gets stdin] "%d:%d" hours minutes

Answer (score 2):

```
puts -nonewline "Enter your name: "
flush stdout
set name [gets stdin]

puts "Hello $name"
```