# How to define array size and elements by user?

Tags: tcl

I'm currently learning TCL and came across a problem with our practice sets. The thought process is that:

1. The script will ask for the size (N) of the array.
2. The user will input the array elements  based on N.
3. The script will print:

   1. size of the array
   2. The elements of the array
   3. Sum of the array elements

I've been searching for a way and found `stdin` as a starting point.

[Update] Tried to code. It does what is required but I think this can be improved.

```
array set elements { }
puts "Enter array size: "
gets stdin N
if {($N < 1) || ($N > 10)} {
    puts "Array size invalid."
} else {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $N} {incr i} {
        puts "Enter element ($i) value: "
        gets stdin value
        set elements($i) "$value" 
        }
    }
    puts "Array size is $N"
    parray elements
    set sum 0
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $N} {incr i} {
        set sum [expr {$sum +$elements($i)} ]
    }
    puts "The sum is $sum"
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you search for previous questions, postings such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842782/input-from-keyboard-in-tcl? Make sure that you make an attempt yourself, and then post your tentative results along with a revised question.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you read the answer to that question; it's highly relevant to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl's arrays (and lists, and dictionaries) will contain the amount of data that you put in them. They don't have a fixed size that you declare ahead of time.

To do an action N times, use a `for` loop like this:

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= $N} {incr i} {
    DoTheActionHereForStep $i
}
```

You will need to use some code to input a value for N, and some more code to read values inside that loop. (You can get the current size of the array with `array size`.) Then use `puts` to print the values back out again, and this is how you might sum the values up:

```
set sum 0
for {set i 1} {$i <= $N} {incr i} {
    set sum [expr { $sum + $theArray($i) }]
}
# Now $sum is the sum of the values in the array
```

As you can see, this is an application of the previous looping operation to the problem of summation.

Comment: I'm deliberately not giving you the whole solution. You learn the language better if I don't, and I think that's the _real_ objective here…

Comment: Hey thanks!  Not really looking for the whole solution. Just want some pointers really. Thanks again! Will post the solution soon.